# Combining multiple mySQL rows without duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have 4 tables in a MySQL database, `suppliers`, `categories`, `subcats` & `listings`.

listings is a join table to allow the many to many relationships between suppliers, categories and subcats, the structure of each is as follows

**suppliers**

```
sp_id      sp_name       sp_email
1          Apple         info@apple.co
2          Samsung       info@samsung.co
```

**categories**

```
cat_id     cat_name
3          Electronics
4          Software
```

**subcats**

```
subcat_id  subcat_name   cat_id
5          Mobiles       3
6          Computers     3
```

**listings**

```
list_id    sp_id         subcat_id
1          1             5
2          1             6
```

I am trying to combine and extract the data together so there is only one entry per supplier with multiple subcategories listed eg:

**RESULT**

```
sp_id      sp_name       sp_email         cat_name / cats        subcat_name / subcats
1          Apple         info@apple.co    Electronics, Software  Mobiles, Computers
2          Samsung       info@samsung.co  Electronics            Mobiles
```

Currently I have the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM suppliers as s
LEFT JOIN listings as l ON s.sp_id=l.sp_id
LEFT JOIN subcats as p ON p.subcat_id=l.subcat_id
LEFT JOIN categories as c ON c.cat_id=p.cat_id
ORDER BY s.sp_id
```

However this outputs multiple entries per supplier, one entry for each category or subcategory associated with it.  Is there an easier way to do it via SQL or with multiple queries in PHP?

I am at the limits of my current knowledge of mySQL and any suggestions or prods in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT  s.*, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_name) catName,
        GROUP_CONCAT(p.subcat_name) subcatName
FROM    suppliers as s
        LEFT JOIN listings as l ON s.sp_id=l.sp_id
        LEFT JOIN subcats as p ON p.subcat_id=l.subcat_id
        LEFT JOIN categories as c ON c.cat_id=p.cat_id
GROUP   BY s.sp_id, s.sp_name, s.sp_email
ORDER   BY s.sp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` in combination with `GROUP_CONCAT` to only show unique values from a certain column with a comma-separated list as one of the values.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`GROUP BY`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm) expression along with the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.  This will allow you to merge together rows which share certain values while concatenating the ones they don't.  For example, in your case this may wind up being something like:

`SELECT s.sp_id, s.sp_name, group_concat(', ', c.cat_name)
FROM suppliers as s
LEFT JOIN listings as l ON s.sp_id=l.sp_id
LEFT JOIN subcats as p ON p.subcat_id=l.subcat_id
LEFT JOIN categories as c ON c.cat_id=p.cat_id
ORDER BY s.sp_id
GROUP BY s.sp_id, s.sp_name;`